# PG ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer when trying to destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I get this error whenever I try to destroy a record. I don't get why this isn't working.

```
PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "Notation"
```

My controller:

```
  def destroy
    Notation.find(params[:id]).destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @commentable, notice: 'Reply was eradicated.' }
    end
  end
```

I've also tried doing it this way:

```
  def destroy
    @notation = Notation.find(params[:id])
    @notation.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @commentable, notice: 'Reply was eradicated.' }
    end
  end
```

How I'm doing it in the view:

```
 <%= link_to comment_notation_path(@comment, notation), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } do %>
            <i class="fa fa-trash small ml-3" title="delete"></i><% end %>
```

The schema:

```
  create_table "notations", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "comment_id"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.text "content"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end
```

Comment: I've seen this error happen when arguments are passed out of expected position.

Comment: @JSpratt, I'm not sure what you mean. I updated my question with another thing I tried.

Comment: Can you post application logs @ddonche?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are passing "Notation" as `:id` in your `destroy` path. Try double checking your `comment_notation_path(@comment, notation)` path

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean here. I am destroying this like I destroy all the other things. In fact, I use the code exactly the way it's done in the [Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/updating_and_deleting_users). I was under the impression you find the record by its id and then destroy it. Is that not what's supposed to happen?

Comment: I think this will solve your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20715190/pginvalidtextrepresentation-error-invalid-input-syntax-for-integer-m